# IIS: hostname breaks website

Tags: windows, iis, virtual-machines, hostname, azure

I have a Azure WindowsVM with a IIS. Everything works fine until i add a hostname in the bindings. Then I get a 404 error.

Comment: I'm sure there is a question in there somewhere.. It's fairly obvious, but we like to actually be asked the question sometimes. :)

Comment: To make it clearer. If i add a hostname, my site isn' available anymore. I get then an 404 error.